# How do I use today's date in the where clause when using Pandasql in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandasql

I am struggling to use some SQL functions in Pandasql as it seems that the same names aren't used for the functions.

For example, using Pandasql in Python I type:

```
q = """ select e.Date, e.SITA, e.Events from df_event e where e.Date >= 
getdate() """
```

This gives me the error that "(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: getdate"

So how do I use today's date in the where clause so that only entries for today and onward are selected?

I further tried this:

```
 q = """ select e.Date, e.SITA, e.Events from df_event e where e.Date >= datetime.date.today() """
```

and it gave me the error "  sqlite3.OperationalError) near "("   "

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you know which DBMS you are using? You have this tagged with sql server and getdate() is a sql server function but your error is pretty obvious you are not using sql server.

Comment: date(‘now’) is SQLite

Comment: @aws_apprentice I am now getting the error that " 'date' is not a recognised built-in function".